# UPDATE MYSQL using REPLACE based on certain criteria of another row having the same value in anothe column

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm super new to SQL and would really like to figure out the this problem.
I work for a travel agency and we have our own online booking website with all room types and stuff.
So basically we're using MYSQL to alter our company's website.
We made a mistake when we translated 'King size bed' into Mandarin and we're now trying to fix this with the REPLACE() function altogether.

The same room is under the same roomid but in different languages.

I believe it is possible to change certain parts of the chinese names only for the rooms based on the criteria of sharing the same roomid AND its english name includes '%king%'.

There are only two identical roomid for each room type in this table. One for English Version and One for Chinese Version.

I've tried to use Update table and self join but I still couldn't figure out the correct and most efficient way of doing this. please help.

Table: room_info

| name | roomid |
| --- | --- |
| Deluxe king | 1 |
| (*chinese name*) | 1 |
| Superior king | 2 |
| (*chinese name*) | 2 |
| Superior queen | 3 |
| (*chinese name*) | 3 |

The result should be something like this:

| name | roomid |
| --- | --- |
| Deluxe king | 1 |
| (*New name*) | 1 |
| Superior king | 2 |
| (*New name*) | 2 |
| Superior queen | 3 |
| **(*Old name*)** | 3 |

**(Old name)** is the part where it should remain unchanged because roomid 3's English version doesn't include the word 'king'

Thank you so much for your help in advance!

My stupid attempt(probably makes no sense but I really tried):

```
UPDATE roominfo
SET name =
CASE WHEN EXISTS(
    SELECT DISTINCT roominfo1.name AS CN, 
                    roominfo2.name AS EN
    FROM       roominfo AS roominfo1
    INNER JOIN roominfo AS roominfo2
            ON roominfo1.roomid = roominfo2.roomid
    WHERE roominfo1.name NOT REGEXP '[A-Za-z0-9]' 
      AND roominfo2.name REGEXP '[A-Za-z0-9]') LIKE '%king%' 
THEN REPLACE(name,'大床','特大床')
ELSE name
END;
```

Comment: please do show what you've tried with a self join

Comment: sorry if what I did makes no sense, like I said I'm new to SQL. However, I actually enjoy it

Comment: helpp plssssssss